# Karate Tests: How to match contains each nested array response with just one schema

Tags: karate

Is possible to match each element of a nested array response (using contains) using just one schema?

I have a set of yml files with request params and response schemas, like this one:

```
response:
  appId: '#string'
  attributes: '#array'
  login: '#string'
  permissions: '#array'
  metadata:
    roles: '##array'
  userData:
    description: '#string'
    employeeId: '#string'
    employeeNumber: '##string'
    id: '#string'
    login: '#string'
    mail: '#string'
    name: '#string'
```

and then, in a reusable feature:

```
* def req = read(<testDataFile>)
* match response contains req.response
```

I can match nested objects with just one schema but I'm not sure if it's possible use the schema to match nested arrays

maybe like:

```
response:
  appId: '##string'
  attributes: '##array'
  attributes[*]:
    key: '#string'
```

or any other expression

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a single "schema" and you have to declare the repeating element separately, as a Karate variable: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation

```
* def foo = { a: '#number' }

* def bar = { baz: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }] }

* match each bar.baz == foo
* match bar == { baz: '#[] foo' }
```